# Can't compare tokens

Tags: c, token

I made a code to tokenize the data in file using C. I want to print some data if the current token is equal to `SIOL`. My problem is `strcmp` won't work. Can you spot any errors? Here is the code. Thank you for your help

```
int main()
{
    FILE* fp;

    char  line[1024];
    char *val1;

    fp = fopen("sample1.txt" , "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        val1 = strtok(line, " ");
        if (strcmp(val1,"SIOL")==0)
        {
            printf("Sucess!");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            while(val1)
            {
                printf("%s\n", val1);
                val1=strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sample1.txt like this:

```
HAHA
SIOL
Hello World!
SIOL
123 4 345 65 756 867 789797
Hello World
```

Comment: Not reproducible http://ideone.com/UMQUcH

Comment: "strcmp wont work" - I think you meant to say "there is probably a bug in my code". Because I'm pretty sure `strcmp` does work. What are the contents of `sample1.txt`?

Comment: You only do the `strcmp` for the first token. What happens if "SIOL" is not the first token?

Comment: Here is the content for my sample1.txt

"HAHA
SIOL
Hello                     World!
SIOL
123 4  345 65 756 867 789797
Hello there"

Comment: @adrianquevada Are all words on the same line, or are there multiple lines? Please edit your question, and paste the content of the file into it. Format the file as code to show precise line breaks (select the content and click `[{ }]` button at the top).

Comment: This is the content of the file 
[{
HAHA  <br/>
SIOL  <br/>
Hello                     World!  <br/>
SIOL  <br/>
123 4  345 65 756 867 789797  <br/>
Hello World   <br/>
 }]

Comment: @adrianquevada Is my editing is correct? Please edit it if there is no properly.

Comment: `val1 = strtok(line, " ");` delimiter `" "` change to `" \t\n"`. E.g `val1 = strtok(line, " \t\n");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, the editing is correct, i'll try to do what you said. Thank you

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much @BLUEPIXY!! Now I can proceed with my project. Thank you. I am new here so i did not expect much for fast response. I'm a student anyway. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your implementation is that it does not treat `\n` properly.

When `fgets` encounters `'\n'` character, it returns it as part of the string. Therefore, both `"SIOL"` strings from your file are returned to your program as `"SIOL\n"` when you tokenize, because they both are at the end of the string. `strcmp` does not consider `"SIOL"` and `"SIOL\n"` equal to each other, so it returns a non-zero value.

To fix this, add `'\n'` to the list of delimiters accepted by your program:

```
val1 = strtok(line, " \n"); // change the second call of strtok as well
```

This will make sure that `strtok` eliminates `'\n'` at the end of the token, and passes a clean token back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much @dasblibkenlight! was a great help!

Comment: By the way @dasblinkenlight, do you have any idea how am i supposed to access the next word when i read line. As you know, I read the input line by line and print the current token, do you have any idea how can I access the next token when I am in the loop? Thank you

Comment: @adrianquevada You cannot access the next token until you call `strtok` again, so the proper course of action when you must look at two tokens at a time is to store the *previous* one, and look at it when you get the next one. This is a little tricky in the context of `strtok`, because you must make a copy of the token before you call `strtok` again, otherwise it may go invalid. Look up copying strings in C to see how to store a copy properly.