# Compare token and a string

Tags: c, token

I made a code to tokenize the data in my input file. I want to compare the current token into the word `SIOL`. If they are equal, print success and exit.

My problem here is, even though my input in file has a string `SIOL`, the condition is always false. It always prints the whole data in the file. 
Here is the code. Hope you can help. Thank you so much

```
main()
{
    FILE *input;
    //char filename[100];

    const char *filename = "sample1.txt";
    input=fopen(filename,"r");
    char word[1000];
    char *token;
    int num =0;
    int ret;

    while(fgets(word, 1000, input) != NULL) //reads a line
    {
        token = strtok(word, " " ); // tokenize the line    

        while(token!=NULL) // while line is not equal to null
        {
            ret = strcmp(token, "SIOL");

            if (ret==0)
            {
                printf("Success!", token);
                return 0;
            }

            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " " ); //tokenize the word     
            num++;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a print statement to your code to print the token with delimiters around it so you can see if there are leading or trailing spaces. It may have leading or trailing spaces or other unexpected characters. for example:  printf("(%s)\n", token);

Comment: Is this question any different from your previous http://stackoverflow.com/q/33718527/2564301? You may want to know that you can use "Edit" to add information to an existing question. Also, please read the [tour].

Comment: I already did that to trace the code ( particularly to trace the value of token). When I display the value of token in my if statement, giving that i put a condition that is always true, the value of token is correct. My problem is it does never entered the if statement.

Comment: @Jongware. They have the same questions but different code approach. Although, i'll just try to delete my previous one.